# Monitoring file change sequenes with Inotifywait

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, files, scripting

Currently I am monitoring the files by using above code, it works as expected. Basically I am monitoring the opened text files and executing commands.

```
inotifywait -m -q /home/TestDirectory |
    while read path action file; do

             if [[ ("$action" == "MOVED_TO") ]]; then
                  #Do something

    
            fi
    done
```

I wonder, how can I monitor the sequences of the inotifywait events and execute command.

For example, how can I execute a command or echo something when there is a **open,access,close_nowrite** event in the directory?

```
/home/TestDir OPEN test.txt
/home/TestDir ACCESS test.txt
/home/TestDIr CLOSE_NOWRITE,CLOSE test.txt
```

Comment: Check the value of the variable `action`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have updated my code and did what you have said, but it still not working and gives a error can you please check it?

Comment: I am getting basically command not founded error, I think I have a syntax problem but I could not figure out.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and copy&paste the full error message there. (Don't use comments to add information and don't describe the error with your own words.) Use https://www.shellcheck.net/ to check your script for errors.

Comment: I have edited my question and deleted the unrelated comments currently my if statement is not working what is the proper way to check these action and read variables?

Comment: You could accomplish this with `awk` but I'm too lazy to write the solution. ;-)

Comment: The script and the output from `inotifywait` don't match: `/testDir` vs `/home/TestDIr` or `/home/TestDir`. Copy&paste everything instead of re-typing. You use variables without assigning a value. Please [edit] your question and make clear what you want to achieve based on real input. I suggest to run `inotifywait -m -q /testDir  -e close_nowrite -e moved_to` first without the `while read...` loop, do some file actions and show the resulting output of `inotifywait`. Then tell us what line(s) you want to match based on what information, e.g. because it contains `CLOSE_NOWRITE`.

Comment: Thank you again for answer, I have edited the question again. Currently my code works perfectly. If the `action` is equal to the some `MOVED_TO`. If statement works. However, as I mentioned before I would like to extract sequences of the `action`. For example, if the action is sequenced as `OPEN ACCESS CLOSE_NOWRITE.CLOSE` I would like to run a command. Yes in this code I can keep track of the single action which is `MOVED_TO`. However, how can I keep track of the sequences of the `action`? (i.e. action sequences). I hope you understand my problem now.